# What is the time complexity on this code? I'm confused

Tags: java, big-o

So I'm solving the leetcode "Valid Palindrome" problem, and I'm unsure what the time complexity of my code is, I thought it was O(n^2) but I wasn't so sure so I used chatgpt to confirm and it keeps saying it is O(n). Apparently the inner while loops run constant.

I can't wrap my head around this for some reason. Any explanations are welcome. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

        int i = 0; 
        int j = s.length()-1;

        s = s.toLowerCase();

        while(i < j) {

            while(i < j && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i))){
                i++;
            }

            while(i < j && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(j))){
                j--;
            }

            if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)){
                return false;
            }

            i++;
            j--;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, the source of this problem appears to be https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-palindrome/

Answer (score 2):

The inner while loops are just used to skip whitespaces or punctuation.
Let's run an example with the palindrome 'g; aag'

i = 0, j = 5
both inner while loops get skipped, since both the char at index 0 and 5 are letters
since both are equal to 'g' we skip the if as well

i = 1, j = 4
now the first inner while loop gets triggered since the char at index 1 isn't a letter or a digit.

i = 2, j = 4
we're still in the inner while loop and the character at index 2 isn't a letter or a digit again

i = 3, j = 4
now the first inner while loop is false, since the character at index 3 is a letter.
the second inner while loop gets skipped since the character at index 4 is a letter

i = 4, j = 3
now the outer while loop is false since i > j.
Therefore, true is returned and it is a valid palindrome.

The complexity is O(n) since every index is only looked at once.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really liked the detailed example you gave, it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like O(n), where `n` is the length of `s`.

At each iteration of `while(i < j)`, the value of `i` will be increased by at least 1, and the value of `j` will be reduced by at least 1. When a non alphanumeric character is encountered, the value of `i`, `j`, or both will be changed by more than one.  The number of comparisons `(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j))` never exceeds `n/2`. So, O(n).

If I may guess as to the source of your confusion, it would be O(n^2) if either or both the inner `while` loops began iteration at the ends of `s`. But, that's not what happens. When there is an iteration of either or both, the number of remaining iterations of the outer `while` is reduced.

Answer (score 1):

The string has only `N` elements.

In your code, the `i = 0` and `j = s.length() - 1` only ever keep getting closer (with each iteration by at least `1`). And when they meet you terminate.

So no matter what happens, you will do at most `N` iterations (doesn't matter how many of those happen in outer or inner loop).

Comment: My main point was that they strictly get closer with each iteration (never stagnating or even getting further away). In the inner while loops, the `i` and `j` get closer only by 1 with each iteration.

Comment: Take string `"       "`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations does not always match the String length, even for a valid palindrome.  Due to the asynchronous way `i and j` are updated, if the outer loop ends and `i and j` are equal, the count must be incremented by 1, otherwise, decremented by 1.

But all that matters is to show that the execution time is `related` to the String length. `O(n)` simply means that the execution time is `linear`, even when you short-circuit the method when two characters don't match.

```
String[] pals = {"radar   ", "ra       dar", "radar             ", "r a d a r",
        "A man, a plan, a canal:    Panama", "Amanapla    nacanalPanama"};

for (String s : pals) {
    boolean result = isAPalindrome(s);
    System.out.println("Length = " + s.length());
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

prints

```
Count = 8
Length = 8
true
Count = 12
Length = 12
true
Count = 18
Length = 18
true
Count = 9
Length = 9
true
Count = 33
Length = 33
true
Count = 25
Length = 25
true
```

The modified methpd

```
public static boolean isAPalindrome(String s) {
    int i = 0; 
    int j = s.length()-1;

    s = s.toLowerCase();
    int count = 0;
    while(i < j) {

        while(i < j && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            count++;
            i++;
        }

        while(i < j && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(j))){
            count++;
            j--;
        }

        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)){
            return false;
        }
        count+=2;
        
        i++;
        j--;

    } 
    count += (i == j) ? 1 : -1;
    System.out.println("Count = " + count);
    return true;
}
```